# What's the best way to calculate Tp,q,r = Sp,q Sp,r in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to turn a series of m input sequences with n items each (s<sub>m,n</sub>) into a tensor where t<sub>p,q,r</sub> = s<sub>p,q</sub>s<sub>p,r</sub>

While my code does work, I feel there must be a better solution. Here's what I got.

```py
# nseqs is the number of sequences
# seq_length is the sequence length
# seq is a list of sequences

output = np.empty((nseqs, seq_length, seq_length))
for n in range(nseqs):
    for i, j in enumerate(seq[n]):
        output[n, i, :] = j
    output[n, :, :] *= output[n, :, :].T
```

More to the point, is there a way to rejuggle the `output` tensor so that the multiplication phase is done in a single step and without those loops?

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk', s, s)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve the desired result with broadcasting. The first dimensions line up, and the others can be coerced into the right shape using unit dimensions introduced with `None`:

```
t = s[:, :, None] * s[:, None, :]
```

You can implement your original approach without loops by assigning the elements of output with broadcasting and then taking the transpose only of the last dimensions:

```
output = np.empty((seq.shape[0], seq.shape[1], seq.shape[1]), seq.dtype)
output[:] = seq[..., None]
output *= output.transpose(0, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't give any numbers or examples, so I made up a small one (you'll have to tell me if it doesn't work for your actual case).

Consider the following:

```py
import numpy as np

nseqs = 4
seq_length = 5

seq = np.arange(nseqs*seq_length).reshape(nseqs, seq_length)
```

Starting with the inner loop, we can achieve the same thing using broadcasting.

```py
output = np.empty((nseqs, seq_length, seq_length))
for n in range(nseqs):
    output2[n] = seq[n,None]
    output[n, :, :] *= output[n, :, :].T
```

Now, the multiplication doesn't actually affect the subsequent loops, so we can split this into two loops.

```py
output = np.empty((nseqs, seq_length, seq_length))
for n in range(nseqs):
    output2[n] = seq[n,None]
for n in range(nseqs):
    output[n, :, :] *= output[n, :, :].T
```

The broadcasting from the first loop is just repeating the elements of `seq[n]` in each submatrix, so we can get the same result using [`np.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html).

```py
output = np.repeat(seq[:,None], seq_length, axis=1)
```

The second loop is just the submatrix `output[n]` multiplied by its transpose. This can be done using [`np.swapaxes`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html), swapping the last two axes (i.e. performing the transpose of the submatrices).

```py
output *= np.swapaxes(output, 1, 2)
```

In the end, your code reduces down to:

```py
output = np.repeat(seq[:,None], seq_length, axis=1)
output *= np.swapaxes(output, 1, 2)
```

Comment: There's no reason to use `repeat` when broadcasting is an option. Also, `transpose` allows you to select the order of the axes, so you don't really need `swapaxes`.